# Cannot hide property: Windows.Forms.TabControl.DrawMode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a custom tab control deriving from `System.Windows.Forms.TabControl` with the following code:

```
[Browsable(false)]
private new TabDrawMode DrawMode
{
    get { return base.DrawMode; }
    set { base.DrawMode = value; }
}
```

I can still see `DrawMode` in the Properties view - what else can I try?

Comment: it's private, make it public or it'll be simply ignored by designer (not overriding base one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your property is `private`, the designer binds to the `Parent` (TabControl), which does have a public `DrawMode` property. By setting your property to `public`, it will look for the property inside your derived `TabControl` and will not appear inside the designer:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public new TabDrawMode DrawMode
{
    get { return base.DrawMode; }
    set { base.DrawMode = value; }
}
```